# How should I store wildflower seeds embedded in a piece of cotton, for several months before planting?

Tags: seeds, germination, seed-saving, wildflowers

I live in Massachusetts, in the Northeast section of the United States. My growing zone is USDA 6a, which means that our winter temperatures can get as low as -10°F/-23.3°C.

I was recently given a heart-shaped piece of 100% recycled cotton embedded with some very small pieces of fresh flowers and some wildflower seeds. They were a memorial gift from the animal hospital where our cat passed away. I'd like to learn how to store them for the winter.

I've never seen seeds presented in this way. The cotton piece, which is called an "adornment," is not in a container, just attached to a piece of lightweight cardboard. I don't know what material is being used to attach it, but I don't want to touch it and risk it breaking or falling off the card.

The instructions say to remove the adornment from the card, plant in 1/4" - 1/2" soil, keep it moist and watch it bloom.

I'm familiar with planting wildflower seeds, but always from a packet which has been sealed until time for planting. Since it will likely be up to 5 months until I can put this in the ground, how should I store it for the best chance of successful germination and flower production? These seeds are very important to our family, and I'd really like to do it properly.

*Click on pictures for close-up views.*

[image: Close-up of seed container]
[image: Entire front of card]
[image: Back of card with instructions]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What a nice gesture of this animal hospital, sorry to hear about your loss.

The best way to keep these seeds is in a dry and cool environment. So not in the fridge (too much moist), and not above the radiator/heater (too hot). If you have a cupboard for storage (is that called a pantry? I am non-native English speaker), that would be the ideal place. The same place where you store stuff like rice and flour. Or a garage, if that is not a very wet or (below zero) cold  place.

I have seen the principle of embedding seeds into a cotton form before, I guess you'll get a heart-shaped bed of flowers when sown. Hope you find a nice spot for it in spring.

Comment: Thanks for your condolences, and for this long, detailed, answer! I'm so glad you responded so quickly because I had the card in a warm room, and would have left it there! I do have a place such as you described, and put it there today. We do call it a pantry, although that term varies. I think I have the perfect spot to plant it in the spring.  It drains well and gets plenty of sun. Daylilles, Shasta daisies and a bunch of other wildflowers are already happy there! Thanks again!!